# How can I add a mouse leave to my file? and how would my code look?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I hover my text file appears.  When I am not appearing I want it to disappear.  How can I do this and what should my code look like?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".button").hover(function(){ $.ajax({url:"demo_test.txt", success:function(result){ $("#div1").html(result); }}); }); 
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="div1"></div>
<a href="#" class="button">Hover me</a> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

Answer (score 1):

According to jQuery documentation, the hover function allows to specify a handler when the mouse enters and when the mouse leaves.

```
$( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )
```

So you can modify your function according to that.

```
$(".button").hover(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "demo_test.txt",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }
    });
}, function () {
    $("#div1").html("");
});
```

Comment: I'd recommend not clearing all the HTML but rather `hide`ing the element

Comment: Then what if the user hovers again, wont the element stay hidden. And again the code is fetching the text file everytime the user hovers so that doesn't really make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".button").hover(function(){ 
       $.ajax({
           url:"demo_test.txt", 
           success:function(result){ 
               $("#div1").html(result); 
           }
       }); 
   })
   .on("mouseleave", function(){
       $("#div1").hide();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dDkc3/)):

```
$('#text').text("SOME TEXT YOU CAN READ BECAUSE YOU ARE HOVERING").css("opacity", "0")
.mouseover(function () {
    $(this).animate({"opacity": "1"}, {duration: 200, queue: false}); 
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate({"opacity": "0"}, {duration: 200, queue: false});
});
```

I didn't include loading of the other file, as no demo file was loadable. But this can be solved easily like this:

```
$.get("demo.txt", function(data) {
   // and here all the above, accordingly
});
```

My proposal also has a nice smoothy animation included, and because it's using `opacity`, the element is still there after being hidden, so the user interface won't move around.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button").mouseenter(function () { 
    // run the ajax request and load the file..
  });
  $('.button').mouseleave(function () {
    // run the code here such as $('#div1').hide() or .css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

This will hide the object once you have an event of mouseleave from the button.

Fiddle for that:

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/SfVrn/1/